# Make background fade out/in

Tags: css, css-transitions, translate

Is there any way I can use CSS3 to fade in and out a solid white background of a `<div>`?
the content should remain visible so just the background should fade.

Any ideas using css3 transitions/transforms?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [transition property](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/01/css-transitions-101/) directly on the `background-color`:

```
div {
   background-color: white;    

   /* transition the background-color over 1s with a linear animation */
   transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

/* the :hover that causes the background-color to change */
div:hover {
   background-color: transparent;      
}
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/axabX/) of a red background fading out on `:hover`.

Comment: Didn't know you could actually animate the background color. I think that's a lot better than my solution :)

Comment: @Husky Transitions are pretty excellent but I'm looking forward to when we can drop all the browser specific prefixes.

Comment: you could use LESS / SASS and use the mixins there. At least makes it bearable if you're using lots of CSS3 properties.

Comment: @Husky I haven't tried LESS/SASS yet, but yeah, the prefixes definitely make a good argument for them.

Comment: thanks for the jsfiddle! here's a forked sample which fades out a background color after load http://jsfiddle.net/divzero/Ddhwx/

Comment: @WilliamDenniss  Thank you!  You just saved me a couple of hours of fooling around!

Answer (score 3):

You may find this useful for examples of image and background color fades: - 
http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/581_cssTransitions/demos.html

However using CSS 3 to do the transition will limit the effect to browsers that don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two `divs` in one container div. The first div contains the white background, the second one gets the content.

Then, use a CSS3 transform to animate the opacity of the first div to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I eventually set the first color inline on the div and the second color (ie. white) external as background-color: white !important; as well as the transition property.