# jQuery or CSS changing and fading background-position on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried a few things but at this point now, i want to fadeout change background position and fadein but not working.... any ideas? or a better solution?

```
  $('.collection-hover a').on("mouseenter touchstart", function(event) {
    $(this).find('.collection-list-hover-desc').fadeIn(1000);
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "-50% 100%"}); 
  });
  $('.collection-hover a').on("mouseleave touchend", function(event) {
    $(this).find('.collection-list-hover-desc').fadeOut(1000);
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "0 0"}); 
  });
```

snippet of html

```
<li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
   <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1491014401" style="background-image: url(&quot;//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1491014401&quot;); height: 108.009px;">
  <div class="collection-list-hover-desc">

    <p>Dein eigener Ruhepol in einer hektischen Welt. Der durch eine Struktur im Inneren formstabile Sitzsack vereint Komfort und Ästhetik.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="collection-list-hover-button">
    <span class="button" style="
    padding: 5px 8px;
">Entdecken</span>
  </div>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: can you provide some html code and if you could include the html, css, and jQuery in a html module by clicking the <> it would make it easier for other s to assist

Comment: Added snippet of html

Comment: This might help.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622822/make-background-fade-out-in>

Answer (score 1):

You want to animate the `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` properties separately.

```js
$('.collection-hover a').on("mouseenter touchstart", function(event) {
  $(this).find('.collection-list-hover-desc').fadeIn(1000);
  $(this).animate({
    'background-position-x': "-50%",
    'background-position-y': '100%'
  });
});
$('.collection-hover a').on("mouseleave touchend", function(event) {
  $(this).find('.collection-list-hover-desc').fadeOut(1000);
  $(this).animate({
    'background-position-x': "0",
    'background-position-y': "0",
  });
});
```

```css
.collection-hover a {
  background: url('http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
.collection-list-hover-desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
  <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa">
    <div class="collection-list-hover-desc">
    <p>Dein eigener Ruhepol in einer hektischen Welt. Der durch eine Struktur im Inneren formstabile Sitzsack vereint Komfort und Ästhetik.</p>
  </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: What do you want to fade in and out exactly? I thought you just wanted `.collection-list-hover-desc` to fade, and that works fine. the background-position change wasn't taking because you need to specify the values separately. And by "all over the place" - what do you mean exactly? I'm using the values you provided. I don't know where you want it to move to, that's up to you.

Comment: say my background image is 200 in height, and showing 100... i want to fade out, change position to show other 100 and fade in etc.... its just like a image sprite, adjusting background position but fading nicely

Comment: @James so you want the element to fade out, the image background position moves while it's faded out, then fade the element back in?

Comment: @James and then reverse that when you un-hover the element? (fade out, move background back to where it was, then fade the element back in?)

Comment: 5am brains dead but ill give it a crack, i have overlaying elements i dont want to fade out just the background

Answer (score 0):

This CSS should point you in the right direction:

https://jsfiddle.net/mikatalk/7aLuk4yL/

```
a {
// your css ...
  position: relative; 
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    background: pink;
    transition: all ease 300ms;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  &:hover {
    &:after {
      transition: color ease 700ms;
      background: red;
      transition: top ease 300ms;
      top: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A super easy way of moving elements on the page as well as changing opacity with jQuery is using GreenSock animations.

https://greensock.com/

They have many free versions that would be exactly what you are looking for in a matter of only a few lines. Something like the following below:

```
<head>
//Calls to the Greensock CDN
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $('#your-element').hover(function() {

      TweenMax.to($('.your-element-to-change'), 1, {alpha: 0.5, left: 100, top: 100});
     })
</script>
</head>
```

That code would animate your element left 100px, down 100px, and change the opacity to 0.5 over the course of 1 second. All of which you can change to meet your needs.